# Custom validation is not taking AllowEmpty option

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have input type file for uploading image. It’s not required field. So I set **allowEmpty** option as true. But my model is not taking this option.
Validation code :

```
public $validate = array(
    'image' => array(
        'isImage' => array(
            'rule' => 'isImage',
            'message' => 'Please upload images only',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            //'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
);

public function isImage($field = null) {
    $file_info = $field['image_path'];
    $image_types = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/jpg", "image/png");

    $result  = false;
    if (in_array($file_info['type'], $image_types)) {
        $result = true;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Or any other rule for validating image type.

Comment: Did you debug($field)? I bet its not the array you expect it to be. its one level deeper (containing key=>value with key being the fieldname "image").

Comment: Sorry. i can't understand you. i am trying to say that 'allowEmpty' property is not working.

Comment: Because  `if (in_array))` will never ever return true here and therefore your method always returns false. try `debug()` as noted above in your isImage method. You will see that that you made a simple mistake. And since the image is an array you cannot just use `'allowEmpty'` either, you need to do this inside your isImage validation method.

Comment: I think its not good method to check inside the custom validation. Is any otherway to get the allowEmpty option value at the isImage function? thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `allowEmpty` won't even matter - it uses the custom method `isImage()` and returns false.  End validation / fail.

If you're going to use a custom validation rule, just use it.  Try something like this within the function:

```
if(empty($field)) return true;
```

Comment: Good suggestion, however, I do agree with the OP that the 'allowEmpty' option is a fairly 'odd' option, basically it's kind of a 'validation within a validation', IMO it should be removed from CakePHP :)

Comment: @thaJeztah - I don't think it's worth removal for the cases where I literally just want to make sure that it's not empty ... `'allowEmpty' => false`

Comment: Well, there's also a Core Validation rule for that, that's what making it confusing for developers new to CakePHP: [Validation::notEmpty()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::notEmpty), `array('myfield' => 'notEmpty');` would achieve the same?

Comment: This isn't the place to debate about something unrelated to the question/answer :)